# Problem Using '!' will be removed in a future release

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2

```
    if let encodingName = response?.textEncodingName as CFString! , convertedEncoding == nil {
        convertedEncoding = String.Encoding(rawValue: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(
            CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding(encodingName))
        )
```

Any ideas for my problem??

Comment: @BobGilmore probably but I cant apply it :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
if let encodingName = response?.textEncodingName as? CFString , convertedEncoding == nil {
        convertedEncoding = String.Encoding(rawValue: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(
            CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding(encodingName)))
}
```

The issue is caused by casting to `CFString!`